# Override log4j.xml configuration over external libraries log4j.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

Since I added a external jar file to my project, the log4j configuration is being picked up from the log4j.xml which is inside the external jar file. The log4j.xml configuration within my application is not getting applied.

Is there a way to override the log4j.xml configuration so that my applications log4j.xml gets picked?

EAR Structure :

\lib\externalJar\log4j.xml

\appweb.war\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml

I can see the warning in the log file as : log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you bundle the the required log4j jar file into your webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory, then the webapps's classloader will load the log4j classes, and you can use your own configuration. This will be separate from the instance of log4j loaded by the ear classloader, and used by the external jar you added.

Comment: I made the change as you mentioned however it still the same. I can see the warning in the log as : log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding my log4j.xml file to commans module instead of web, the commans jar file resides in lib folder under ear file.

Comment: Glad to hear that, but you may have broken logging for the external jar that you added, which was using it's own log4j config file, unless you merged your log4j config with the config required by that external jar, so all the log4j config is in one file for that (ear) classloader